# C構造体のポインタをRUSTで扱うには

Tags: rust

下記の様なC構造体のポインターをRUSTで扱うにはどうすれば良いですか？

c code.

```
typedef struct {
 int value;
} DATA;

DATA* new_data(){
  return (DATA*)malloc(sizeof(DATA));
}
void del_data(DATA* data){
  free(data);
}
```

下記の様に試したのですが、errorが取れません.

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x700002fba9b0: pointer being freed was not allocated
malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

rust code

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct DATA {
    count: u32
}

#[link(name = "clibrary", kind = "static")]
extern "C" {
    fn new_data() -> *mut DATA;
    fn del_data(data: *mut DATA);
}
fn main(){
  unsafe{
    let raw = new_data();
    del_data(raw);
  }
```

Comment: 手元で再現できないのですが、ビルド方法について教えてもらえませんか？ちなみに動く例: https://github.com/termoshtt/rust_c_ffi_build_example

Comment: 頂いたコードと見比べていたらC側のコードにエラーがありました！ Cのコードにエラーがあっても動いてしまうのですね。お騒がせしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

試行錯誤しているうちにC codeのnew_dataのreturn文が消えてしまっていました。
returnが無くてもコンパイルが通ってしまいメモリ確保が行えずdel_dataにて
クラッシュしていました。